# Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What could be the problem here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQRdJ.png)

I keep getting an error: Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
public fun Text(text: String, modifier: Modifier = ..., color: Color = ..., fontSize: TextUnit = ..., fontStyle: FontStyle? = ..., fontWeight: FontWeight? = ..., fontFamily: FontFamily? = ..., letterSpacing: TextUnit = ..., textDecoration: TextDecoration? = ..., textAlign: TextAlign? = ..., lineHeight: TextUnit = ..., overflow: TextOverflow = ..., softWrap: Boolean = ..., maxLines: Int = ..., minLines: Int = ..., onTextLayout: ((TextLayoutResult) → Unit)? = ..., style: TextStyle = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.material3
public fun Text(text: String, modifier: Modifier = ..., color: Color = ..., fontSize: TextUnit = ..., fontStyle: FontStyle? = ..., fontWeight: FontWeight? = ..., fontFamily: FontFamily? = ..., letterSpacing: TextUnit = ..., textDecoration: TextDecoration? = ..., textAlign: TextAlign? = ..., lineHeight: TextUnit = ..., overflow: TextOverflow = ..., softWrap: Boolean = ..., maxLines: Int = ..., minLines: Int = ..., onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) → Unit = ..., style: TextStyle = ...): Unit defined in androidx.compose.material3

Comment: In your dependencies, do you have both Material 2 and Material 3?

Comment: like @CodePoet said, check in your file if you have multiple imports for Text:

import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.Text

Comment: Resolved it. Was a problem with my dependencies. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the Error in dependencies where you should only have 1 implementation for material

I also got this error due to 2 times implementing material3 and with its version. I removed 1 and it resolved my error

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when using Text composable and as already given answer here.

I tried and found in gradle(Module) file that there are 2 compose material 3 dependencies are there and one is outdated as well.

So by removing one and and updating the remaining one resolve my issue as well.